# Vue conditional * css style loader

Tags: node.js, vue.js, webpack

My vue app is shared between web page and electron app on touch device. On this touch device I want to include extra style. So in my App.vue there is:

```
<script>
  var is_electron = process.hasOwnProperty("versions") && process.versions.hasOwnProperty("electron")
  var is_embedded = is_electron && require("electron").remote.process.argv.includes("-e")
</script>
<style>
* {
  transition-property: none !important;
  transform: none !important;
  animation: none !important;
  cursor: none !important;
}
</style>
```

How can I conditionally include this * style ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the platform-specific styling is minimal, I would suggest to use some helper classes. You can even style subcomponents by scoping the css within one of these selectors.

```
<template>
  <main :class="classes">
    <!-- Hello world -->
  </main>
</template>

<script>
  var isElectron = process.hasOwnProperty("versions") && process.versions.hasOwnProperty("electron")
  var isEmbedded = isElectron && require("electron").remote.process.argv.includes("-e")

  export defualt {
    name: 'App',

    computed: {
      classes () {
        return {
          electron: isElectron,
          embedded: isEmbedded
        }
      }
    }
  }
</script>

<style>
.electron:not(.embedded) * {
  border: 1px solid blue;
}

.embedded:not(.electron) * {
  /* What kind of sorcery is this? */
}

.electron.embedded * {
  border: 1px dotted red;
}

main:not(.electron):not(.embedded) * {
  border: 1px dashed green;
}
</style>
```

Comment: Why in computed and not in data ?

Comment: In this case it would have worked in a data initialisation function. However, I find that in my applications classes change from time to time. The data initialisation function also becomes crowded with different things that are not really related to each other. A computed property at worst adds a function call and a watcher on variables that do not change. In this case I prefer the clearness of a computed property name over adding it to the data attribute.